# Running SQL script with psql on Windows gives "EROR: character with byte sequence 0x9e in encoding "WIN1254" has no equivalent in encoding "UTF8""

Tags: postgresql, windows

I was trying to transfer data to my PostgreSQL database with the command

```bash
psql -h localhost -U postgres -d test -f C:\file.sql
```

but it gives me an error like

```
EROR: character with byte sequence 0x9e in encoding "WIN1254" has no equivalent in encoding "UTF8"
```

How can I solve this problem?. I used Windows 10 and Postgres version 12

Comment: That's appropriate, 0x9e has [no assigned character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1254#Character_set).  Use chcp to select the correct code page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19162055/psql-shell-uses-code-page-850-windows-uses-1252-how-to-solve-change-console-co

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to figure out what the encoding of the file is. Let's assume it is UTF-8. Then you can start your `cmd.exe` and type:

```bash
set PGCLIENTENCODING=UTF8

psql -h localhost -U postgres -d test -f C:\file.sql
```